# JDeveloper JSP web application page not found 404

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to learn developing web applications using JDeveloper and JSP.
The thing is that although the JSP pages are under web-inf, when I deploy the application (weblogic server) the only page that is accessible is the one listing some records from a database. The other ones, for editing, are not found (Error 404). Also, I have a login page which last time I tried it, it worked. Now , I only see 404...Why?

I have to mention that I have disabled auto compile function in Jdeveloper for some reason and I did run "make"...(for all JSP, classes)

Help, please...

Comment: what you pass in url to access this jsp??

Comment: I pass the following : http://127.0.0.1:port_no/project_name/page_name.jsp   But , I observed that if I right-click on a page and select run it runs ok. But from the application it won't run. The links are ok. I doubled-checked them

Comment: when you right click and run jsp page same link will be in url??

Comment: Yes. From JDeveloper view project -> run jsp => ok. (url loaded in firefox). Yes, same link. Cannot understand???

Comment: I do understand but if your jsp under web-inf. you can not access directly from url.

Comment: To resume, if I run the project, JDev deploys application and opens in default browser the url of a page which displays some records from database. I have links on that page, links which directs me to other *.jsp files but the server returns error 404: page not found. Found that I do have some errors on some primary key constraints, though...if that matters...But, still I don't see why those pages cannot be accessed. I do not have much experience in JSP...

Comment: :-) no worry just try to solve that if there is an error.

Comment: Very curious. Tried to enter some data using SQL Developer. It works. Seems that the problem resides in JSP scripts somewhere..So, why do I get the following: "java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (store.prod_PK) violated"? Could this be the culprit?